# LDAP users and web application

Tags: php, architecture, active-directory, ldap

We built a web application (running on our intranet) that relies on our LDAP directory (active directory) for it's users. Instead of 'syncing' the directory users with say a 'user' table in our application database (MySQL) we use the LDAP directory just like we use databases.

When creating a relation between an entity pulled from MySQL and an LDAP user we use the user GUID (which is a unique string).

Our directory will never have more than 300 users (never). We installed a dedicated DC (Domain Controller) to serve our application request. Network latency is not an issue.

In our code we could replace a few lines of code to switch from using LDAP to using MySQL and a 'user' table (data mappers are awesome)

Would you do this (no 'user' table syncing)? What are your arguments against this (way of doing it)?

**edit**

We do use a 'user' table but it's very *simple* so sql joins are not really a problem, we know it will have better perfomance with a *full* user table but are looking for other arguments against using LDAP

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `_id` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `guid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`_id`)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not do it. I would sync the users data except for the password on every login. That way you have the current data of your application in its database and you can use your databases join features to get all the relevant information without going to query different systems. I'd only use LDAP for authentication and perhaps a model of LDAP-Group based authorization.

- That way you do not need to hassle with passwords and any password
  policies.
- And after login you are completely independent from the LDAP-server.
- A missing LDAP server won't affect already logged in users only new
  logins would not work.

And even though the objectGUID is unique it is unique throughout your LDAP and not necessarily your application.

We often have the issue that in LDAP a user us newly created instead of renamed when the users name changes (due to marriage or divorce f.i.). But you might not want to create a new user in that case in your app. With your own users table you can simply change the ObjectGUID for a user and the users app-internal id stays the same but links to a completely new user in LDAP.

Comment: the problem I see is that if a user doesn't log in the application his profile will not be up to date with what's in the LDAP directory (this is a small problem for our phone book but could be big problem for human ressources 'modules'), the solution would be to sync all user account every x hours/days/.. or look how old is a profile on every request and we're trying to avoid both

Comment: It strongly depends on your use case. When you have an application in mind that needs up to date information of ALL users at ALL times then you will have to use the LDAP as database directly. Or at least query the LDAP for these informations according to the users ```objectGUID```. It won't make sense to update these informations every X hours! But even then I'd probably use a users-table to have the flexibility of changing the LDAPs structure without having to think about the application. But I presume thats personal liking and depends also on the LDAP-Admins ;-)

Comment: Your approach of using a "small" user-table would be the one I'd use ;-) I'd probably sync the users name in on every login but that's not the issue here! That way you can flexibly alter the users reference-dataset in the LDAP when something should change and you aren't too tightly coupled to the LDAP. But all relevant information can be used from the LDAP.

Comment: hah! those LDAP(AD) Admins want to delete user account after the user leave (retirement/etc.) and this is a big problem for us and this is exactly why we're looking for arguments :D, thank you sir

Comment: we've had exactly these issues and thats why we sync the users data on login. And we're not alone. Confluence wiki f.i. does it also when connected to an LDAP. They sync all relevant infos every x hours.

Comment: 0) group based authZ is absolutely appropriate; 1) `objectGUID` is unique in time and space; 2) if you are relying on the directory merely for authN, authZ and profile data you are still done with the directory after the login process; 3) directory admins creating new users instead of properly maintaining existing users is a process problem;4) if the domain is unavailable you still would no be able to authenticate and there are likely larger problems afoot. my 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely do that for authentication, the base user profile,  and user status. The AD entry for the user is highly likely to me more current than the data you have for the user. It removes the need for you to manage passwords for users. You don't need to store them or provide a facility for changing them. When the user status is disabled in Active Directory your user won't be able to use your applications anymore. If the user's name, email, phone number changes in AD then you will always have the most up to date data and you don't have to provide a facility to manage it.

The `objectGUID` is perfect way to link your account as it is unique and immutable.