# LDAP - Looking for a better way to manage users in PHP/Mysql

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

those are my prerequisites:

- Users are managed through Active Directory
- In LDAP they are assigned to groups which determine the rights of those users
- LogIn through NTLM

Right now I check and see if a USER is member of a certain group before displaying some data:

```
if(is_allowed(USER, '(memberof=CN=Repairgroup,OU=Laboratory,OU=Organization,OU=MyBusiness,DC=somedc,DC=local)')):  
    display some data
endif;

function is_allowed($check, $filter) {
    // connect to ldap
    $ldapconn = ldap_connect(LDAP_HOST) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
    // binding to ldap server
    ldap_bind($ldapconn, LDAP_USER, LDAP_PASS) or die("Error trying to bind: " . ldap_error($ldapconn));

    // search for $filter
    $result = ldap_search($ldapconn, LDAP_TREE, $filter) or die("Error in search query: " . ldap_error($ldapconn));
    $data = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);

    // check if user is part of LDAP_TREE
    if (!in_multiarray($check, $data)):
        // all done? clean up!
        ldap_close($ldapconn);
        return false;
    endif;
    // all done? clean up!
    ldap_close($ldapconn);
    return true;
}

function in_multiarray($elem, $array) {
    while (current($array) !== false):
        if (current($array) == $elem):
            return true;
        elseif(is_array(current($array))):
            if(in_multiarray($elem, current($array))):
                return true;
            endif;
        endif;
        next($array);
    endwhile;
    return false;
}
```

Now if I want to assign a User to a ticket for example I run the following:

```
// connect to ldap
$ldapconn = ldap_connect(LDAP_HOST);
// binding to ldap server
ldap_bind($ldapconn, LDAP_USER, LDAP_PASS);

// search for $filter
$result = ldap_search($ldapconn, LDAP_TREE, LABORATORY);
$data = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);
utf8_encoder($data);
for ($i=0; $i<$data["count"]; $i++):
    echo "<tr><td><label class=\"label\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"user[]\" value=\"".$data[$i]["cn"][0]."\" />".$data[$i]["cn"][0]."</label></td></tr>";
endfor;
ldap_close($ldapconn);
```

And into the database I just put the name. If I've more users assigned to it I seperate them with ',' like that:

```
$users = NULL;
        foreach($c_post['user'] as $value):
            $users = $users.$value.", ";
        endforeach;
```

Result would be something like that in my database: `Alex Foo, Peter Bar`

And reading from the DB I just use a simple explode to seperate them.

`$iduser = explode(", ", $row->iduser);`

also in order to get the current user browsing I use this filter:

```
// User based on Windows-Login (Look up user currently browsing)
define('LDAP_SELF', '(sAMAccountName='.substr($c_server['REMOTE_USER'], 11).')');
```

Now having this set up like that it is very easy to add user, manage their rights and so on. Even a destinction between *Head of department* and so on is fairly easy once you grasp on those filter LDAP uses.

But for me it becomes painful to use in my code. Now I want to send messages and get some statistics based on user which would end up with a bind every time to LDAP and look up the users. It is the first time I'm using LDAP / Active Directory and before that I just had my table in MySQL which was filled with users and their ID. It just seemed more easy to store, manage and do actions based on the IDs in my code then it is now.

- Is there anything I can improve in my code or way of using LDAP?
- Am I using LDAP "correctly"? (I know the answer will be based on opinion but as long as I'm not abusing LDAP with my code I'm fine with it I guess)
- How save will it be to bind everytime to LDAP compared to just have the users in my database?
- If unsafe doing it with LDAP should I run once a day some script an populate a table with the users?
- More easy way to perform something like below?

**As an example**

I want to edit the User assigned to a ticket. First I select the value from my table, then explode it and list the users. Now I would need to combine them and check before updating my database if those users are still part of the Active Directory and have sufficient rights.

1. SELECT from Database
2. Explode and display
3. Bind to LDAP to show all other users
4. Check if Users still are present and have rights in LDAP
5. combine users
6. update database

Thank you so much for your time :)

---

**What I ended up with:**

To make things easier I have this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["DN"]) && !isset($_SESSION["username"])):
    // connect to ldap
    $ldapconn = ldap_connect(LDAP_HOST) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
    // binding to ldap server
    ldap_bind($ldapconn, LDAP_USER, LDAP_PASS) or die("Error trying to bind: " . ldap_error($ldapconn));

    // search for $filter
    $result = ldap_search($ldapconn, LDAP_TREE, '(sAMAccountName='.USER.')') or die("Error in search query: " . ldap_error($ldapconn));
    $data = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);
    utf8_encoder($data);
    ldap_close($ldapconn);
    $_SESSION["DN"] = $data[0]["dn"];
    preg_match('/^CN=(.+?),(?:CN|OU)=.+/', $_SESSION['DN'], $matches);
    $_SESSION["username"] = $matches[1];
endif;
```

If I need to display users I have this:

```
// connect to ldap
$ldapconn = ldap_connect(LDAP_HOST) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
// binding to ldap server
ldap_bind($ldapconn, LDAP_USER, LDAP_PASS) or die("Error trying to bind: " . ldap_error($ldapconn));

?>    
<div id="container">
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <?php

echo "<tr><td>Repairgroup</td></tr>";

$result = ldap_read($ldapconn,
    "CN=Repairgroup,OU=Laboratory,OU=Organization,OU=MyBusiness,DC=domain,DC=local",
    "(objectClass=*)",
    ["member"]
);
$data = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);
utf8_encoder($data);

foreach($data[0]["member"] as $k => $v):
    if(!is_int($v)):
        preg_match('/^CN=(.+?),(?:CN|OU)=.+/', $v, $name);
        echo "<tr><td><label class=\"label\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"user[]\" value=\"".$v."\" />".$name[1]."</label></td></tr>\n";
    endif;
endforeach;
?>
   </tbody>
 </table>
</form>
```

Then I would store one or more DNs in my database seperated with `|` and later when I had to display just the name I use this:

```
preg_match_all('/\bCN=\b(.+?),/', $row->iduser, $name, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
echo "<td class=\"worker\"><span>";
for($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++):
  echo "<p>".$name[$i][1]."</p>\n";
endfor;
echo "</span></td>\n";
```

This is an example of my regex: https://regex101.com/r/s6PbOR/1/

And to check if someone has access:

```
if(is_allowed($_SESSION["DN"], 'CN=Repairgroup,OU=Laboratory,OU=Organization,OU=MyBusiness,DC=somedc,DC=local')):  
    display some data
endif;
```

Thank you Esteban for guiding me towards this! :) Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Is there anything I can improve in my code or way of using LDAP?
> - Am I using LDAP "correctly"? (I know the answer will be based on opinion but as long as I'm not abusing LDAP with my code I'm fine with it I guess)

You use your LDAP directory as a RDBM backend. You should try to use it as it is intended : a hierarchical database.

In your code you :

1. Request every user which have the attribute `memberof` set for a group
2. Check if the `USER` is part of this group

BUT : You have the group `DN`, LDAP has mechanisms which entrust that a user to be part of a group should exist in the directory.

SO: What I would have done is :

Retrieve the `member` attribute of the group :

```
$result = ldap_read($ldapconn,
"CN=Repairgroup,OU=Laboratory,OU=Organization,OU=MyBusiness,DC=somedc,DC=local",
"(objectClass=*)",
["member"]
)
```

This saves you the load of searching into the directory because you access directly the entry providing the unique id to read it (the DN)

> - How save will it be to bind everytime to LDAP compared to just have the users in my database?
> - If unsafe doing it with LDAP should I run once a day some script an populate a table with the users?

LDAP is a protocol which is built to handle a ratio much higher of read/search than write, so as long as the request/search is optimized, there should be no problem to look for a user every time you need it.

> - More easy way to perform something like below?

- Instead of storing some display name of users in the ticket table I would store the DN of the user. It has 2 benefits

  - Allow you to `ldap_read` the user entry without having to perform a search to find this information beforehand
  - The explode array that you will obtained from your DB can be compared direclty with the `member` attribute array returned by the `ldap_read` on the LDAP group (as seen previously)
- Check if users are still presents :

  - The users which will be present in the `member` attribute of the group should exist in the directory, so the list you need to check is only the one present in the database and not in the group
  - If they should not be assigned anymore to the ticket because they are not in the group, then there is no more check for presence, else you just need to `ldap_read` the users entry without retrieving any attribute, if the user does not exist you will have a LDAP error : `32 no such object`

It will be much more faster and efficient than making multiple searches

If you do it this way, to check if a user is present in a group and is allowed, the code you posted will only be :

```
// USER would be the DN in this case
if(is_allowed(USER, 'CN=Repairgroup,OU=Laboratory,OU=Organization,OU=MyBusiness,DC=somedc,DC=local')):  
    display some data
endif;

function is_allowed($check, $dn) {
    // connect to ldap
    $ldapconn = ldap_connect(LDAP_HOST) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
    // binding to ldap server
    ldap_bind($ldapconn, LDAP_USER, LDAP_PASS) or die("Error trying to bind: " . ldap_error($ldapconn));

    // search for $dn
    $result = ldap_read($ldapconn,
    $dn,
    "(objectClass=*)",
    ["member"]
    ) or die("Error in search query: " . ldap_error($ldapconn));
    $data = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);
    ldap_close($ldapconn);

    return in_array($check, $data[0]['member']);
}
```

(NOTE: you will need to tweak this a little to handle the error code return by a user deleted from the LDAP directory)

Comment: First of all thank you for this answer! I was looking into it and it was very helpful. Yet I've two questions regarding your solution:**1.** How would you enter the DNs into the Database? *My idea would be to store the DN and separete them with "|'" for example. To display the Name it should be enough to extract later the CN=Name Lastname and display it instead of doing a ldap_read again.* **2.** When you say handle the error code return you talk about the `Error 32 no such object`?

Comment: I was reading up on [Hierarchical Database Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_database_model) and [Relational database management system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) and took a closer look into user management in php with ldap found with your keywords given in your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28787550/8188398 or https://www.null-byte.org/development/php-active-directory-ldap-authentication/ and also http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LDAP-HOWTO/   This greatly improved my usage of LDAP and my understanding on how things work. Thanks again!

Comment: @floGalen To store the DNs, it's up to you what sperator you want to use as there is no invalid character in a DN (some need to be escaped though), so if more of a guide line on your system to not use your separator in a DN than an absolute rule common to all LDAP DNs. For your 2nd point, yes I talked about the `Error 32`. It's only from memory so I'm not sure if a `ldap_read` on a non existing DN will return an error or an empty result, so in case it is the error, you have to handle it instead of doing a `die` on the script.

Comment: Thank you for your response, one last miracle I've now is the following: `$_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"]` gives me `Domain/FBar` as the user. Based on that I did my ldap_search and knew which User is currently browsing. Is there a better way or would I do, lets say, a ldap_search and store the users DN in a Session for example?

Comment: @floGalen It is completely up to what you need to do with the user identity. Doing the search to retrieve the DN with some informations and store the DN for future use is what I would do to avoid doing this search on each refresh of the page